# Angularjs dynamically added ng-model is not accessible by $scope, shows undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am creating form, where few fields are dynamic, ng-model is added dynamically.
Ex.:

```
form.append("<input type='hidden' name='paymillToken' value='" + token + "' data-ng-model = 'formdata.token'/>");
```

This fields shows undefined while I try to access using `$scope.formdata.token`

Following is another scenario where I am adding fields via ajax.

```
    angular.forEach(data.data, function(obj, key) {
        list+='<div class="items text-center"><img src="assets/uploads/discs/'+obj.image+'" class="img-circle"><br><input type="radio" id="chkDisc'+obj.id+'" name="disc_id" value="'+obj.id+'" required data-ng-model="formdata.disc_id" /></div>';
    });
    $scope.discslist = $sce.trustAsHtml(list);
```

This model disk_id is not accessible too.

Comment: If you're using `ng-model`, no need to use `value` attribute.

Comment: Can you provide plnkr link ??

Comment: You are adding the input but not compiling it.  ngModel and input are directives and need to be compiled to work. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: what is the purpose of `form.append()` here?  angular can dynamically generate content via many means based on your data, there is rarely any reason to operate on the DOM in this manner.  This seems to be the JQuery way of doing things, not the Angular way.   Angular encourages you to program against your data, whereas JQuery style is programming against the DOM.

Comment: to me, this just reads, I don't know the angular way to map this value in the HTML, so I'm using JQuery to "dynamically" generate the fields, and I don't understand why angular doesn't see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, to expand on my comment and a bit more on what everyone else here is saying to you, the main issue you're having is inherent in your approach.  The way you're trying to manipulate the DOM is very un-AngularJS.

In AngularJS, when you want to change what is displayed to the user (the view), you make changes to your model (your controller scope).  That means, you have to set up your view to be able to respond to those changes.  We do that with directives and expressions in Angular.

You're probably already using directives to respond to changes in your model whether you realize it or not.  ngRepeat, ngModel, ngShow, ngIf, ngInclude, are a handful you're probably familiar with, and even forms and form elements like inputs are actually directives in Angular.  When you use these, a change in your model (such as loading data into the controller scope) signals to Angular that it should check whether that change affects any of the directives in your view, and if so, respond to it by updating the view.

In order to do this, Angular needs to know which parts of the model are connected to which parts of the view.  It makes these connections when it **compiles** the html elements that are added to the page.  This compile process happens automatically when you load an Angular app.  After that, it's up to us to tell Angular when to compile html that is added to the page.

More often than not, we do this without even realizing it.  For example, when you use the ngView directive, it will compile the template for each route that it loads, so that all of the directives in your template are properly linked with their associated model.

I know this is a long explanation, but there are two very important points here that are essential to learning AngularJS:

1. To change the view, you change your model and let the directives (and expressions) on your page respond to those changes.
2. When you add html elements to the page, if you want AngularJS to be able to use them in your view, they must be compiled first.  The compile process should be done via a directive (either a built in one or a custom one).

So, how does all of this apply to your question?

First, I'm guessing that you're breaking both rules by trying to manipulate the DOM via a controller.  Even if it is *possible* to use $compile in a controller, [using a controller to change the DOM is bad practice and simply wrong to do](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) (read the part in that link to the doc that specifically states: *Do not use controllers to: Manipulate DOM...*).  A good rule to remember when you're learning AngularJS is that the **only** time you should ever be using JQuery or JQLite inside Angular is when you are creating a custom directive.

**Okay, so how do you solve your question?**  Use a directive.  It looks like you've got a case where you're trying to iterate over an object called data and add some inputs that correspond to the data.data property.  This sounds like a job for **ngRepeat**.

The first thing you need to do is add your data to your controller and make sure it is accessible to the view.  The easiest way to do this is by injecting $scope into your controller and setting the data on a scope variable.  In its simplest form, that might look something like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $http.get('/some/url/that/returns/the/data').
     success(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

Now that we have the data somewhere that we can access from the view, we can use it with the ngRepeat directive in our html, something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <div class="items text-center" ng-repeat="disc in data.data">
    <img ng-src="assets/uploads/discs/{{disc.image}}" class="img-circle"><br>
    <input type="radio" id="{{'chkDisc' + disc.id}}" name="{{disc.disc_id}}" value="{{disc.disc.id}}" required data-ng-model="formdata[disc.disc_id]" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your approach works and well, but when page loading it will show image path undefined, how could I prevent image loading untill repeat works.

Comment: Sorry, that was my oversight.  I should have changed your src to [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue. By updating the value and not the model angular has no idea that the value in the field has been updated. As the first commenter said updating in this manner is completely unnecessary when using ng-model.

Comment: K, I am new with AngularJs can you let me know which way I could handle it,
See I am adding another case which is also not accessible by model

Comment: First, utilize the compile functionality as suggested to add the new field. You should also utilize a directive and templates for adding the HTML, not magic stringing it in what appears to be a controller. The other question I have is what case are you using that isn't accessible? If it is an event of some sort you can bind that event to the element using a directive.